# Mail RFC embedded image using cid for text/plain

Tags: image, email, mime-message

While I remember email messages could contain embedded images in HTML and plain text I noted today Outlook 2013 and Windows 10 Mail app does not display it.

Is this something the RFC standard has removed the "[cid:]" definition?

Below is the formatted mail:
(save as *.eml to display its content)

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 6 Feb 2018 10:12:53 +0100
From: Test User 2 <test.user2@lab.local>
Subject: TEst in plain text
Thread-Topic: TEst in plain text
To: Test User 1 <test.user1@lab.local>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_60A9E784-DBBE-4378-9A84-01D36C2226AF_"

--_60A9E784-DBBE-4378-9A84-01D36C2226AF_
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

test

[cid:BBCLOGO@23AD2D600E]


--_60A9E784-DBBE-4378-9A84-01D36C2226AF_
Content-Type: image/jpg; name="23AD2D600EF4C69FF4D5479A8BB7FE73.jpg"
Content-ID: <BBCLOGO@23AD2D600E>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename="23AD2D600EF4C69FF4D5479A8BB7FE73.jpg"
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--_60A9E784-DBBE-4378-9A84-01D36C2226AF_--
```

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to [RFC 2387](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387), "The MIME Multipart/Related Content-type"

To refer to an attachment by the value of its `Content-ID` (CID) MIME header field, it's as simple as:

```html
<img src="cid:BBCLOGO@23AD2D600E">
```

Note that your body must be HTML, such as `Content-Type: text/html; chaset="us-ascii"`, as indicated by [RFC 2045 §5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5).

Outlook should do this automatically when you place images in your message body.  If you need further help configuring that, there is probably a more appropriate Q&A site than (the programming-centric) Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know that it currently works for text/html only. I actually wanted to have an official statement as I remember in past it was also working for text/plain using "[cid:xxxxxxxx]"

Comment: I do have a faint recollection of seeing that in old emails, though I don't think it ever *rendered* the image (except insofar as the image appeared below the body, as it would do regardless of that ~tag). I assumed it was merely a cue that there was such an attachment (which is more relevant when the CID contains the file name, though it didn't in your example). Maybe somebody can dig through old RFCs to see if there's some reference to it, but email has never been good at strictly following the specs.